# DataType.Currency attribute fails on $ sign

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Working in ASP.NET MVC, I have a view model with an Amount field.  The amount field is tagged as a Currency type using a data annotation like so...

```
[DisplayName("My Amount")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
```

I am also formatting the Amount as currency in the view using a format string...

```
<%: Html.TextBox("Amount", string.Format("{0:c0}", Model.Amount)) %>
```

This results in the Amount being formatted as $100 when it is displayed in the view.

However, when the Amount is submitted back to the server the "$" inserted by the format string causes the Amount to fail validation as currency.  Can anyone tell me how to set this up so that I may still have the Amount formatted with a "$" but it will also validate as a currency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pull that "$100" string back in, run it through [Decimal.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx), assigning the *result* to your `Amount` property (note that TryParse returns its decimal amount, if successful, in an `out` parameter; its return value is boolean). You can specify a `NumberStyle` (see the examples at that link) which will deal with the $ sign.

Comment: What if you need to tie in a range? I had issues where the range will see the commas and periods and flag it as an error. I see a similar issue here: search for range within the comments. A post by  Vincent G - Tuesday, September 13, 2011 8:01:43 AM.